# UIImage with image sequences

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage, image-manipulation

I have lot of png sequences that I need to loop through and display on the ipad.

but then it goes out of memory eventually crashing the application.

I worked around skipping each alternate frame to avoid memory errors.

Any way that I can manage the memory, allocation/release, I don't see anything like release for this kind of memory allocation, nor there is any alloc.

Any other memory efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this

iboutlet uiimageview *animationview;

in .h file

and in .m file

```
animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(157,354, 45, 100)] ;
animationView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"],
     ...................................,
    [UIImage imagenamed :@"imageN.jpg"],
     nil];

    animationView.animationDuration = .65;
    animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [animationView startAnimating];
 [self.view addSubview:animationView];
    [animationView release];
```

Comment: please see my comment above, i am looking to avoid out of memory errors. getting rid of the image from memory as soon as it's done displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there's no way to manage this kind of animation. If it works for you, great. If it doesn't, you need to use something else for it. A video sequence or a manually-replaced image in an image view (slow, and also prone to memory issues), or something in GL.